# Using COM Interop to use a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, com, interop

I have to use a DLL in my project that is a .NET assembly. I have to use C++ for this project. I'm a relative beginner to programming, so my knowledge doesn't extend too far. I was told COM Interop is one way to get the DLL to work in my project (the other being C++/CLI). The problem is I have ZERO idea how to begin, as I've never done anything like this before, and the Microsoft documentation on the matter isn't really helping.

If anyone can even point me in the right direction, that would be much obliged.

Comment: If you have no clue about either COM or C++/CLI then using C++/CLI is more likely to bring this project to a good end.  COM has a pretty steep learning curve.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to research how to write in C++/CLI. I just started programming a few months ago, so this is all sort of new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some good resources to get you started:

- [Introduction to COM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633/Introduction-to-COM-What-It-Is-and-How-to-Use-It)
- [COM from Scratch](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6726/COM-from-scratch-PART-ONE) (Covers using COM from C++)
- [MSDN's section on COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694363%28VS.85%29.aspx)

That being said, you'll also need to make sure that your .NET project is setup to expose the classes via COM.  Make sure to turn on `Register For COM Interop` in your project settings, and flag appropriate types with [`[ComVisible(true)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) (Unless you make the entire assembly `ComVisible`, in which case you would flag types you don't want to expose with `[ComVisible(false)]`)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried turning on Register for COM Interop, but it's not an option in my project. I looked at the documentation for it, and apparently it only works in VB or C# projects? It's probably my fault for not being more specific. The project is a C++ console application and the DLL is a .NET assembly. I would prefer to use a C# project, but it has to be C++. I was told using C++/CLI might be easier, but that's another area I've never dealt in before, either. But thank you for your help.